# How can I optimize ArcMap Editor's streaming mode for use with a tablet such as the Wacom Intuos?

Tags: arcmap, digitizing

I have the Wacom Intuos 4 Large tablet which I use occasionally outside of ArcGIS. I now need to digitize a large volume of polygons from aerial imagery and am finding the tablet's ArcGIS functionality cumbersome.

The pen tip works fine in a regular mode where I tap it to create a vertex (albeit far too easy to mistakenly engage a double click) but **I would like to be able to delineate features as if I were doing it on paper - a fluid hand motion**.  I turned on streaming and set it to 5 map units which is OK but when I reach a point where I need to lift and reposition my hand on the tablet or pan the page while still digitizing, streaming does not stop when I lift the pen from the tablet.  Ideally, I would like the streaming to behave exactly as it does in Google Earth - streaming pauses when the tip is lifted and resumes when a pressure is again applied to the tip. GE also generalizes sketches on completion not while sketching as ArcMap does - this makes the finished product simple but precise.

Alternatively, I used ArcMap's Tablet toolbar which streams beautifully to produce "ink" sketches. However, when I lift the pen from the surface, line is interrupted and while this is fine for polylines, the line interruptions create artifacts when creating polygons.

**How to I set up ArcMap Editor streaming so that streaming pauses when I lift the pen tip from the tablet's surface?**

OR

**How can I draw an ink sketch and pause drawing when the pen is lifted and have the sketch resume in a new location where the pen touches the surface?**

OR

**How can I draw an ink sketch and snap to another ink sketch start/end node?**

I am off to give it this a try in QGIS...

Comment: This question deals with streaming and freehand but some related issues are covered [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93423/can-i-resume-continue-digitizing-a-polygon-feature-from-any-vertex/93444#93444)