# Resuming (continuing) digitizing polygon feature from any vertex in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, digitizing

When I digitize in ArcMap with a Wacom tablet and a pen I often accidentally double click and finish my sketch.  More often then not the accidentally finished sketch crosses itself.  I would like to be able to continue digitizing the existing sketch from the last vertex or any vertex I choose.  The OOTB "Continue Feature" tool does not work in this situation because it just adds a new feature part to the sketch and does not resolve the "crossing segment" artifact.

I also tried using the [ESRI's "Modify by Continuing Sketch" tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=8556F0FF-1422-2418-A042-0CD3CD910DF9) (developer sample) which does what I need it to do but it always resumes digitizing from the "Last" (red) segment.  In theory this is correct unfortunately last vertex is often not the last digitized vertex - Editor seems to assign the last (red) vertex randomly.

My question is: As a workaround, **I would like to be able to assign the "last vertex" to the actual last or any vertex in the sketch I choose.  Can this be done?**

*Figure: Example of an accidentally finished sketch (this is a polygon with a transparent fill) in which the last vertex was assigned to polygon boundary crosses itself not where I finished digitizing (which is indicated by an arrow).  This also happens with simple polygons - last vertex becomes another random vertex, not the actual last vertex I created in the sketch.*

[image]

Comment: from my experience, the best workaround is to digitize lines.

Comment: Well, that's a great idea actually. Thanks. The easiest way to digitize freehand is in Google Earth. QGIS and ArcGIS are not there yet.

Comment: configure the Wacom tablet to not response to the double click. http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11022

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz.  I tried that. That would solve my problem but I don't seem to be able to turn of the double tap/double click on my Intuos4

Comment: Seems windows Tablet and touch features are taking over the Wacom functionality rendering it useless.  I turned off windows Table PC Component Features and the Tablet PC input Services and the pen double click action is not only engaged when tapping the same point. Not perfect but much better.  Thanks for steering me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

@Mapperz suggested I configure my tablet not to response to double click.  I tried doing this but the features were non-responsive.

It seems that the Pen and Touch and default windows tablet features and services are taking over some of the Wacom Intuos functionality. 
After I turned of the Table PC Input Services and then Tablet PC Component Features and unchecked all the options in the Pen and Touch Windows Settings, the tablet works much better with ArcGIS.   Double tapping still cannot be fully turned off as double tapping in the same location still executes a double click but it is MUCH better because prior to these changes double click action executed on any double tap even if I was moving. (Interval based) Now, double tapping is location based; double click will only execute when double tap occurs in the same location.

I found [other suggestions](http://viziblr.com/news/2013/6/23/the-windows-and-wacom-tablet-nightmare-is-over.html) that recommend turning off the "Use Windows Ink" option in the Wacom Driver.  This option is only available in the latest version of the drivers.

The above also turns off other annoying windows features such as the Dynamic Feedback rings, Press-and-Hold, Drag Delay, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reshape feature tool seems to allow you to edit the polygon after you accidentally finish the sketch.